# Is the extension of flows from the product of a system with a K system to itself relatively K?

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, entropy

Let $(X,\mathcal{B},\mu,T)$ be a probability measure preserving system. It is said to be a K-system if any non-trivial factor of it has positive entropy. Also we can define the notion of relatively K for a non-trivial extension $\pi:(X_1,\mathcal{B}_1,\mu_1,T_1) \to (X_2,\mathcal{B_2},\mu_2,T_2)$, which means that for any $(X_3,\mathcal{B}_3,\mu_3,T_3)$ an intermediate factor, with the factor map $\pi':(X_3,\mathcal{B}_3,\mu_3,T_3) \to (X_2,\mathcal{B_2},\mu_2,T_2)$ and the entropy of $(X_3,\mathcal{B}_3,\mu_3,T_3)$ is strictly greater than $(X_2,\mathcal{B_2},\mu_2,T_2)$ unless $\pi'$ is an isomorphism.

Now suppose we have a K-system $(X_1,\mathcal{B}_1,\mu_1,T_1)$ and an arbitrarily system $(X_2,\mathcal{B_2},\mu_2,T_2)$, then we have a natural factor map from the product system of $(X_1,\mathcal{B}_1,\mu_1,T_1)$ and $(X_2,\mathcal{B_2},\mu_2,T_2)$ to $(X_2,\mathcal{B_2},\mu_2,T_2)$. My question is that is true that this extension relatively K?

I think if one wants to prove the claim, then it seems one needs to try to construct a non-trivial factor of $(X_1,\mathcal{B}_1,\mu_1,T_1)$ from the intermediate factor. But I could not find a way to do this.